# java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java

I experienced the following problem 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

with the code as follows. 
Thank you for help!

```
PriorityQueue<SoftReference<Element<K, V>>> heap;
heap.add(new SoftReference<Element<K, V>>(newElement));
```

definition of class Element is as follows

```
class Element<K, V> implements Comparable<Element<K, V>>{
        long timeStamp;
    K key;
    V val;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element<K, V> o) {
    return new Long(timeStamp).compareTo(o.timeStamp);
    }
    Element(long ts, K key, V val){
        this.timeStamp = ts;
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
        }
}
```

Comment: Naturally, References do not implement Comparable. It doesn't matter what the reference points to, its the reference itself PriorityQueue wants to compare, not the referred element. Your design is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PriorityQueue` created without a custom `Comparator` expects its elements to implement `Comparable`, and `SoftReference` does not. Try creating your `PriorityQueue` with a custom `Comparator` that can compare `SoftReference`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works well for me. Here is the code. Any additional comments are welcome. `class SoftReferenceComparator<T extends Comparable> implements Comparator<SoftReference<T>>{

 @Override
 public int compare(SoftReference<T> o1, SoftReference<T> o2) {
  return o1.get().compareTo(o2.get());
 }
}` `Heap = new PriorityQueue<SoftReference<Element<K, V>>>(sizeLimit, new SoftReferenceComparator<Element<K, V>>());`